# why the application not display the first view in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I am trying to display my first view on screen .I used all concept of angular .But it not display or load my template .I didn't get any error .but it not load on html why here is my code

http://goo.gl/VbBnqg

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.auth').config(Routes);


    Routes.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];
    function Routes($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        console.log("config call")
        // Default
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('signin');
        // Application
        $stateProvider
            .state('signin', {
                url: '/sign-in',


                templateUrl: 'js/auth/template/login.html',
                controller: 'authenticationCntrl'
            })
    }

})();
```

actually my login.html not load why ? why it is not loaded..

here is my project
https://dl.dropbox.com/s/x8s0xbllm270rq5/firstfroject.zip?dl=0

Comment: What is the url in your browser when you launch this code? I'd say that you should use url path in .otherwise('/sign-in'), but you used state name instead. If it is not the reason, could you provide plunker to test that?

Comment: url is this ..http://localhost:63342/firstfroject/www/index.html#/signin ..Actually I am not able to make directory in plunker that why I am not taking plunker editor

Comment: here is my project https://dl.dropbox.com/s/x8s0xbllm270rq5/firstfroject.zip?dl=0\

Comment: Yup, you should redirect otherwise to '/sign-up' not 'signup' - you can pass path there not a state name. Btw. if you type url by hand #/sign-up it is working, so it is just a matter of wrong path.

Comment: @MarekSadura but I studed that it pases the state name .not url

Comment: r you sure that we need to pass the url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll explain the situation a bit more in answer.
According do docs (otherwise() section):  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

You can pass string (url path) or function to otherwise(). If you would like to use state, you should pass a function that will invoke that state like this:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location){
  $injector.invoke(['$state', function($state) {
    $state.go('stateName'); //in you case 'signup'
  }]);
```

It will invoke state service and go to 'signup', which has route configured to '/sign-up'. Overall effect will be the same.